# JSON model in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, loopback-address

I want to return such model from my `customer` table.

```
{
  "1521544526409": {
    "address": "",
    "city": "",
    "company": "Atoy oy",
    "email": "henry.tuohimaa@atoy.fi",
    "forename": "Henry",
    "moreinfo": "",
    "note": "Customer related notes",
    "postalcode": "",
    "surname": "Tuohimaa",
    "tel": "0503383882"
  },
  "1521544680834": {
    "address": "",
    "city": "",
    "company": "",
    "email": "",
    "forename": "dsfdfs",
    "note": "",
    "postalcode": "",
    "surname": "sdffd",
    "tel": "fdsdsf"
  },
}
```

Can anyone tell what should my model look like?

Current model is as below.

```
{
  "name": "customer",
  "plural": "customer",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "Id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true
    },
    "FirstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "LastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Company": {
      "type": "string"
    },    
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

---

My *customer.js* file.

```
const connector = app.dataSources.tovio.connector;

const sql = 'select * from customer INNER JOIN \
            address ON address.Id = customer.AddressId';
module.exports = function (Customer) {
    Customer.getDetails = function (data, cb) {
        connector.execute(sql, null, (err, instance) => {            
            cb(null, instance);
        });
    };
Customer.remoteMethod(
        'getDetails', {
            http: { path: '/getdetails', verb: 'get' },
            accepts: { arg: 'Id', type: 'number', http: { source: 'query' } },
            returns: { type: 'array', root: true }
        }
    );
}
```

My URL is as follow. - http://localhost:3000/api/customer/getdetails

and response is

```
    [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Lindsay",
    "LastName": "Baxter",
    "Company": "Pearl Architectural Design",
    "Email": "laron_jones",
    "Telephone": "773-617-5179",
    "Note": "Note1",
    "MoreDetails": "More1kjk",
    "AddressId": 1,
    "IsActive": 0,
    "Created": "2018-04-18T04:38:55.000Z",
    "Creator": null,
    "Modified": "2018-04-18T04:38:55.000Z",
    "Modifier": null,
    "Address": "4267 Cherry Ridge Drive",
    "City": "Webster",
    "PostalCode": "14580"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "James",
    "LastName": "Baxter",
    "Company": "Hudson",
    "Email": "evert.ksd",
    "Telephone": "484-319-7836",
    "Note": "Note3",
    "MoreDetails": "More3",
    "AddressId": 1,
    "IsActive": 0,
    "Created": "2018-04-18T04:38:55.000Z",
    "Creator": null,
    "Modified": "2018-04-18T04:38:55.000Z",
    "Modifier": null,
    "Address": "4267 Cherry Ridge Drive",
    "City": "Webster",
    "PostalCode": "14580"
  },
]
```

Comment: You can edit your question no need for long bonus comment.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// customer.js
module.exports = function (Customer) {
  Customer.getDetails = function (id, done) {
    Customer.findById(id, function (err, customer) {
      if (err || !customer) return done(err, customer)

      let res = {
        // now you have the customer object, build your response
      }

      done(null, res)
    })
  }
  
  Customer.remoteMethod(
    'getDetails',
    {
      path: '/getdetails/:id', verb: 'get' },
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'id', type: 'number', required: true},
      ],
      returns: { type: 'array', root: true }
    } 
  )
}
```